# Is boost::object_pool synchronized?

Tags: c++, boost

Is boost::object_pool synchronized?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'synchronised' as this term doesn't have a specific meaning in C++ like it does have in Java, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ doesn't specify anything about thread-safety, so if it isn't mentioned it likely doesn't deal with threading. Sometimes, Boost provides things that can be thread-safe out of the box, this is not one of them.

Wrap access to the pool in a [mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/pool/doc/implementation/mutex.html).

Answer (score 1):

`boost::object_pool` is not synchronized for concurrent access and freeing of objects to and from pool. but if you want pool with synchronization,   `singleton_pool` from boost is the one. There are few restrictions on how to start using `singleton_pool`, but they are pretty fair and applicable for all applications. Please see below notes from boot documentation from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces.html) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/singleton_pool.html).

> Object Usage vs. Singleton Usage
>
> Object Usage is the method where each Pool is an object that may be created and destroyed. Destroying a Pool implicitly frees all chunks that have been allocated from it.
>
> Singleton Usage is the method where each Pool is an object with static duration; that is, it will not be destroyed until program exit.
>   Pool objects with Singleton Usage may be shared; thus, Singleton Usage
>   implies thread-safety as well. System memory allocated by Pool objects
>   with Singleton Usage may be freed through release_memory or
>   purge_memory.

`singleton_pool` usages restrictions

> The underlying pool p referenced by the static functions in singleton_pool is actually declared in a way that it is:
>
> - Thread-safe if there is only one thread running before main() begins and after main() ends -- all of the static functions of singleton_pool synchronize their access to p.
> - Guaranteed to be constructed before it is used -- thus, the simple static object in the synopsis above would actually be an incorrect implementation. The actual implementation to guarantee this is considerably more complicated.
>
> Note that a different underlying pool p exists for each different set of template parameters, including implementation-specific ones.